# Merge values from two forms on submit

Tags: jquery, html

I have two forms on one html page.  Using jQuery, is it possible to have the data from both forms go into the POST data when the first is submitted?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One approach is to copy all of form2's inputs into form1 once the data validation check succeeds. This assumes you are not doing an AJAX submit.

```
// new onsubmit function for form1
function form1_onsubmit()
{
    if (!EntryCheck()) return false; 

    $('#form2 :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#form1');

    return true;
}
```

If you wanted to cater for hitting submit twice, possibly because of submit fail from the server, we would need to remove any copied inputs before copying in new ones.

```
// new onsubmit function for form1
function form1_onsubmit()
{
    $('#form1 :input[isacopy]').remove();

    if (!EntryCheck()) return false; 

    $('#form2 :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().attr('isacopy','y').appendTo('#form1');

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This almost worked, then I noticed that in the documentation for `clone()`: "For performance reasons, the dynamic state of certain form elements (e.g., user data typed into textarea and user selections made to a **select**) is not copied to the cloned elements. When cloning input elements, the dynamic state of the element (e.g., user data typed into text inputs and user selections made to a checkbox) is retained in the cloned elements."

Comment: To append two serialized..... `$("form1").add($("form2")).serializeArray()` .

Answer (score 94):

jQuery serialize supports multiple form elements, So it is possible to do:

```
$('#form1, #form2').serialize();
```

And for your case, you can do:

```
$('#form1').submit(function() {
    var action = $(this).attr('action');
    if (!EntryCheck()) return false;
    $.ajax({
        url  : action,
        type : 'POST',
        data : $('#form1, #form2').serialize(),
        success : function() {
            window.location.replace(action);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I already have `onsubmit="return EntryCheck()"` for form1.  Where `EntryCheck()` is a validation function.  Will this cause issues?

Comment: This doesn't work for me still.  It doesn't take me to the action page

Comment: @Brian - I've edited my answer. Note that it will call your action place twice - once in POST method to send data, and once in GET method to go there. You can check which request method is performed and act accordingly.

Answer (score 9):

Lachlan Roche's solution only copies the elements, but not the values.  This will take care of values as well, and can be used to handle either form submission:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var submitter = {
    combine: function (form1, form2) {
      $('#' + form1 + ' :input[isacopy]').remove();
      $('#' + form2 + ' :input').not(':submit').not('textarea').not('select').each(function() { $(this).attr('value', $(this).val()); });
      $('#' + form2 + ' textarea').each(function() { $(this).text($(this).val()); });
      $('#' + form2 + ' select').each(function() { $('option[value!="' + $(this).val() + '"]', this).remove(); $('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]', this).attr('selected', 'selected'); });
      $('#' + form2 + ' :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().attr('isacopy','y').appendTo('#' + form1);
      return true;
    }
  };
</script>
```

And your form tags would look something like (notice the form ids passed to the function are switched):

```
<form name="my_first_form" id="my_first_form" method="post" onsubmit="if (!submitter.combine('my_first_form', 'my_second_form')) { return false; }">
...
<form name="my_second_form" id="my_second_form" method="post" onsubmit="if (!submitter.combine('my_second_form', 'my_first_form')) { return false; }">
```

Form validation can fit in there wherever you like - it would make most sense if your validator was another function of the submitter object, or vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

> Another  way to merge your own data into form serialize

```
        var data = {};
        data['key'] = 'value';

        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            dataType : 'json',
            type : 'post',
            data : $(this).serialize() + '&' + $.param(data),
            success : function(data) {

            },
            error : function() {

            }
        });
```

Comment: $.param({key: 'value', anotherKey: 'anotherValue'}) - a more visual example of what $.param may accept.

Answer (score 4):

While the other answers address the question you asked, it may be worth considering why you have 2 separate forms, if you want to send the contents of *both* forms whenever the user submits one.

If you are using 2 different forms to separate them visually, a better approach may be to use CSS to place the elements on the screen as you desire. That way, you are not relying on the presence of Javascript to ensure that your forms are populated correctly.

Comment: Given I'm using "formvalidator.net" that validates inputs either onBlur or onSubmit, how would you go about toggling visibility after validation?

I didn't really see a way beyond breaking up the form into 2 where the first submit validates and shows the second form, whereas the last submits all the data.

Answer (score 3):

This is a clean JavaScript approach for merging two forms. I test it with a POST request with Prototype and jQuery and it works. This is the thing:

```
var data1 = document.getElementById('form1').serialize();
```

NOTE: `form1` is form's id .You need to set it within `<form id="form1"></form >`

```
var data2 = document.getElementById('form2').serialize();
```

NOTE: `form2` is form's id. You need to set it within `<form id="form2"></form >`

Now you have two `var`s and two serialized data (arrays). You can easily merge them. Your form will have assoc. array and you can get a problem when you try using `concat` function.

```js
var mergeddata = data1 + '&' + data2;
```

This is it! You can easily send them through ajax call. For example, `Prototype.js`:

```
 new Ajax.Request(url, {
                        method: 'post',
                        parameters: mergeddata, ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I used below code to submit two forms' data in my website.

The idea is that you get the *multiple forms data* using `serialize` and combine that data and equalize that to `data` parameter of the `$.ajax` function.

.

```
// submits two forms simultaneously
function submit_forms(form1_id, form2_id)
{
    var frm1_name = $("#" + form1_id).attr('name');
    var frm2_name = $("#" + form2_id).attr('name');

    if (frm1_name == frm2_name)
    {
        alert('The two forms can not have the same name !!');
    }
    else
    {
        var frm1_data = $("#" + form1_id).serialize();
        var frm2_data = $("#" + form2_id).serialize();

        if (frm1_data && frm2_data)
        {
            $("#div_busy").html('<strong>Processing...</strong><br /><img id="busy" src="./images/progress_bar.gif" border="0" style="display:none;" />');
            $("#busy").fadeIn('slow');

            $.ajax(
            {
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "process_sticker_request.php",
                   data: frm1_data + "&" + frm2_data,
                   cache: false,

                   error: function()
                   {
                        $("#busy").hide('slow');
                        $("#div_busy").css({'color':'#ff0000', 'font-weight':'bold'});
                        $("#div_busy").html('Request Error!!');
                   },
                   success: function(response)
                   {
                        $("#div_busy").hide('slow');
                        $("#hdnFormsData").html(response);

                            // open popup now with retrieved data
                            window.open('', 'popup2', 'toolbars = 1, resizable=1, scrollbars=1, menubar=1');
                            document.getElementById("prt").action = 'win_sticker.php';
                            document.getElementById("prt").target = 'popup2';
                            document.getElementById("prt").submit();

                            // reset the action of the form
                            document.getElementById("prt").action = 'list_preview.php';

                   }
             });                
        }
        else
        {
            alert('Could not submit the forms !!');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although your answer is far beyond the scope of the OP's question it did help me see how you guys pull off the AJAX request's progress bar, so thanks for that^^

Answer (score 0):

Using `serialize` to combine forms and submit using ajax was working for me until I added an "export" button (to send data as an excel file). For that I needed to do a full postback. So I ended up with this method. It chooses the appropriate merge technique, and fixes some of the issues with buttons, selects and textareas along the way:

```
$("body").on("submit", ".combineForm", function () {

    var frm = $(this);
    var action = frm.attr("action");
    var method = frm.attr("method");
    var target = frm.data("updateTarget");

    var combined = $(".combineForm");

    //get the submit button that was clicked
    var btn = $(this).find("button[type=submit]:focus");
    var btnName = btn.attr("name");
    var btnValue = btn.attr("value");

    //create an in memory form to avoid changing the existing form
    var f = $("<form action='" + action + "' method='" + method + "'/>")

    //Browsers send the name and value of the clicked button but serialize, clone and our copy can't
    //So add a hidden field to simulate browser behaviour
    if (btnName)
        f.append("<input name='" + btnName + "' type='hidden' value='" + btnValue + "' />")

    if (btnValue === "export") {//exporting to a file needs full submit

        //merge forms with class 'combineForm' by copying values into hidden inputs
        // - cloning doesn't copy values of select or textareas
        combined.find(":input").not("submit").each(function () {
            var inp = $("<input name='"
                        + $(this).attr("name")
                        + "' type='hidden' value='"
                        + $(this).val() + "' />")
            f.append(inp);
        });

        f[0].submit();
        return false;
    }

    //merge forms for ajax submit
    var data = combined.serialize() + "&" + f.serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url: action,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (html) {
            $(target).html(html);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function that Merge Two Complexe, cames from different Forms, as:

```
// Each Object came from serializeArray()
var obj = $('form').serializeArray();
obj = JSON.stringify(obj);
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
```

// Example

```
obj1 = [
        { name: 'name1', value: 'value1'},
        { name: 'name2', value: 'value2'},
        { name: 'name3', value: 'value3'}
    ];

obj2 = [
        { name: 'name4', value: 'value4'},
        { name: 'name2', value: 'value5'},
        { name: 'name1', value: 'value6'}
    ];


function mergeTwoJsonObj( obj1, obj2 ){

    var obj3 = [];
    for (var index in obj1) {
        obj = {name: obj1[index].name, value: obj1[index].value};
        obj3.push(obj);
    }
    for (var index in obj2) {
        obj = {name: obj2[index].name, value: obj2[index].value};
        var isExist = false;
        var existAt;

        for (var j in obj3) {
            if( obj3[j].name === obj2[index].name){
                isExist = true;
                existAt  = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!isExist) {
            obj3.push(obj);
        } else {
            obj3[j].value = obj2[index].value;
        }

    }

    obj3 = JSON.stringify(obj3);
    obj3 = JSON.parse(obj3)

    return obj3;

}
```

For the example obj1, and obj2 it returns:

// Example

```
 obj3 = [
        { name: 'name1', value: 'value6'},
        { name: 'name2', value: 'value5'},
        { name: 'name3', value: 'value3'},
        { name: 'name4', value: 'value4'}
    ];
```

I wish it helps