# Serialize multiple forms together?

Tags: jquery, serialization, json

Can you serialize multiple forms into one so that only one post or ajax request is made? I have searched around and it is all for submiting each form separently via post/ajax.

Comment: [Have you tried it? http://jsfiddle.net/C4pd5/](http://jsfiddle.net/C4pd5/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Merge values from two forms on submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341001/merge-values-from-two-forms-on-submit)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

When you use the jQuery `serialize()` function, it simply turns your form into a string in the format `a=1&b=2&c=3`.  So you can certainly apply this function to two forms and concatenate the result, with an `&` between them, and use the result in your ajax call.  You'd want some checks to make sure neither string is empty when you do the concatenation.

Answer (score 139):

If you run `$('form').serialize()` on a page with multiple forms, it will correctly serialize **all** the forms into one string.

To include only certain forms, use `$('#form1, #form2').serialize()`

Comment: @472084 I tried that `$('#form1, #form2').serialize()` approach, but didn't get it to work, only last form would get posted. I had 1big form that I had to break up into 2, where the second only appears after the 1st validates (that's why I had to break it into 2). So the first submit wouldn't submit data, but only validate, while the last would serialize both forms and submit all the data. I eventually had to serialize both forms separately and concatenate them with an `&` to make it work. Any documentation you know of that could give me a direct read on why that would fail? I'll keep googling

Answer (score 26):

I like the answer from [Jleagle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9280884/682755) above.

if you are more specific about the forms , use

```
$('#detailsform,#levelForm').serialize();
```

the above line will return a string value. like `customId=08071992&cort=01&empId=7777`

**you can avoid unwanted fields by adding the attribute `disabled="disabled"` to the input fields OR in other words *"disabled" fields won't get serialized.***

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that `input[disabled]` are not included in `$().serialize()`.

Answer (score 2):

For me the solution was:

```
$('#firstForm').append($('#secondForm').children());
$('#firstForm').submit();
```

the result in my case - single GET query with both forms in one query string.

Answer (score 0):

```
function mergeAndSerialize(f1, f2) {
    let d1 = $(f1).serializeArray(), d2 = $(f2).serializeArray();
    d2.forEach(f => !d1.some(o => o.name === f.name) && d1.push(f));
    return $.param(d1);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.