# jquery integrate form parameter in one object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There are many forms in my page. I want to merge them in one object and submit them in one object. But I find `serializeArray()` or `serialize()` do not match my request, the serializeArray function will generate a array object and serialize is used by get model, it is not an object.

is there a jquery or local function can merge them in one object.

I have one solution but it is not perfect, loop the array object generated by serializeArray, use `$.extend` to merge them in one object. is there a better method?

kindly help, thanks.

Comment: I think that's complicating things... Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280720/serialize-multiple-forms-together

Comment: Thank you, but I think it is not what I want. the result will be a string matching a certain format.

Comment: Why do you need an object then?

Comment: there is a plugin in my page designed by myself, there are many jquery.extend in progress, so I need an object when ajax submit, using data:object.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself, I Imitate the serialize function and create a simple plugin. if there is any defect, please point out, thanks

```
(function($) {
$.fn.paramJson = function(a, traditional) {
    var prefix, s = [], add = function(key, value) {
        // If value is a function, invoke it and return its value
        value = $.isFunction(value) ? value() : (value == null ? ""
                : value);
        s[s.length] = "\"" + encodeURIComponent(key) + "\"" + ":" + "\""
                + encodeURIComponent(value) + "\"";
    };

    // Set traditional to true for jQuery <= 1.3.2 behavior.
    if (traditional === undefined) {
        traditional = $.ajaxSettings
                && $.ajaxSettings.traditional;
    }

    // If an array was passed in, assume that it is an array of form
    // elements.
    if ($.isArray(a) || (a.jquery && !$.isPlainObject(a))) {
        // Serialize the form elements
        $.each(a, function() {
            add(this.name, this.value);
        });

    } else {
        // If traditional, encode the "old" way (the way 1.3.2 or older
        // did it), otherwise encode params recursively.
        for (prefix in a) {
            buildParams(prefix, a[prefix], traditional, add);
        }
    }

    // Return the resulting serialization
    return "{" + s.join(",").replace(r20, "+") + "}";
};
$.fn.serializeJson = function() {
    return $.parseJSON($.paramJson( this.serializeArray()));
};
```

})(jQuery)