# post json + form data in single ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, post

I have a json and form data to send in an ajax post call, how can I combine both:

something like

`data : $("#my-form").serialize() + $({ pkeys: ckeys, page: cpage }).serialize()`

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + "pkey/action/edit",
    data: $("#my-form").serialize() + {
        pkeys: ckeys,
        page: cpage
    } //get this right
}).done(function (data) {
    alert("success");

});
```

Comment: What kind of result are you looking for? The `.serialize()` function returns the form in URL encoded form, not an array.

Comment: @MikeShi Result like abc=def&ghi=jki

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize multiple forms together?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280720/serialize-multiple-forms-together)

Comment: @hjpotter92 I don't have multiple forms, instead one form and some json data

Comment: Did you check the link in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10668872/1190388) post?

Comment: Would just adding `+'&pkeys='+ckeys+'&page='+cpage;` instead of `$({ pkeys: ckeys, page: cpage }).serialize()` not work?

Comment: @MikeShi did the job, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.param` exactly meets your requirement.

```
$("#my-form").serialize() + '&' +
$.param({
    pkeys: ckeys,
    page: cpage
})
```

see further example through [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/).

Answer (score 0):

Adding `+'&pkeys='+ckeys+'&page='+cpage;` instead of `$({ pkeys: ckeys, page: cpage }).serialize()` works.