# How to submit multiple HTML Forms as One Form to a PHP script using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

**NOTICE** *I realize this is very unusual and not really the "right" way but it is how this Wizard plugin is setup and out Wizard is already built using this jQuery Plugin so I would like to figure out a way to submit the data to my PHP script now as 1 FORM POST*

I am working on a Form Wizard that uses Bootstrap.  It is different from anything I have ever worked with before in JavaScript and Frontend development for a FORM because instead of being 1 HTML FORM with all the form fields in a single form, it is broken into separate Forms.

The code for the jquery plugin for this Wizard is located here https://github.com/sathomas/acc-wizard

There is a live Demo to see the above Wizard in action here http://sathomas.me/acc-wizard/#prerequisites

Each Step in the Wizard is wrapped in it;s own `<form>` tags.

So in the last/final step of the Wizard, instead of a `NEXT` button, there is a `Submit` button.

Now obviously this only Submits the very last `<form>` that the Submit button/field is attached to.

I need to somehow make the Submit button submit all the Forms in the Wizard to a PHP script and have it `POST` as one single Array of items instead of each Form being separate.

I am not good enough with JavaScript to know exactly how to go about doing this as I have never seen it done before!  jQuery is also available to use in this project.  I would appreciate any ideas and help in getting this to work and being able to submit multiple forms as 1 form with the last submit button.

**Form 1**

```
<form id="form-test-1">
  <p>
        Select a Channel Letter Sign Type
        <select name="channel_type" class="form-control" id="channel_type" size="1">
          <option value="1">Front Lit</option>
          <option value="2">Reverse Lit (Halo)</option>
          <option value="3">Front Lit &amp; Back Lit</option>
          <option value="4">Reverse Pan Exposed Neon</option>
          <option value="5">Open Face</option>
          <option value="6">Reverse Pan Exposed Neon &amp; Backlit</option>
        </select>
  </p>
<div class="acc-wizard-step"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="">Next Step</button></div></form>
```

**Form 2**

```
<form id="form-test-2">
  <p>
        <select name="channel_type" class="form-control" id="channel_type" size="1">
          <option value="1">Front Lit</option>
          <option value="2">Reverse Lit (Halo)</option>
          <option value="3">Front Lit &amp; Back Lit</option>
          <option value="4">Reverse Pan Exposed Neon</option>
          <option value="5">Open Face</option>
          <option value="6">Reverse Pan Exposed Neon &amp; Backlit</option>
        </select>
  </p>
<div class="acc-wizard-step"><button class="btn btn-primary" type="">Next Step</button></div></form>
```

---

**....about 10 more of these FORMS that act as Steps in a Wizard**

The last Step/Form has the Submit button which needs to submit all these Forms as if they were 1 single large form!

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="form-ContactInfo">
         <legend>Contact Information</legend>
     <div class="control-group">
                    <div class="controls">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" id="name" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name" aria-invalid="false">
        <p class="help-block"></p>
       </div>
           </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="controls">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" id="email" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email" aria-invalid="false">
    <div class="help-block"></div></div>
      </div>
<div class="control-group">
                  <div class="controls">
      <input type="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone" id="phone" required="" data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number" aria-invalid="false">
    <div class="help-block"></div></div>
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" id="returnDepth" name="returnDepth" value="0">
      <br>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" id="submit-all">Submit Quote Request</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't submit multiple forms via a traditional post. You can with ajax, but I would still consider it the 'wrong' thing to do here.   You should consider using 1 form tag, and instead use logical DIVs for section/steps and show/hide as appropriate, making sure each field has a unique name.

Comment: @j08691 Ideally, I think it should somehow get the values of all the separate Form fields and put them into a single array to submit, instead of posting separate forms with AJAX, any ideas?  This is not my concept, it is how that script posted is setup but I need to use it for it;s Wizard like functionality

Comment: It's not very clean, but if you must use multiple forms you can use JS to serialize all the data from all of the forms on submit, stuff that into a hidden field in the last form, then pull the data from that in your PHP script.

Comment: @Samsquanch this is pretty much in my head how it needs to be done, just not sure how to do it

Comment: Personally, I would consider using AJAX to submit data to the server and have the server store the data from each step in session and/or database. This will allow much cleaner use for jump back and forth between steps.  So if user needed to go back to first step make a change and then go back to third step, you could re-populate the data in the third step.

Comment: @jasondavis see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280720/serialize-multiple-forms-together

Comment: Could you not store the information from each form on sever as you go, using a session for example?

Comment: @MikeBrant that sounds like a good Idea that I had not considered, thanks!

Comment: @j08691 I agree, it seems like a horrible way to do it but unfortunately the plugin does it this way and of course it does not show a way to submit the data, only the Front End appearance of the Form Wizard

Comment: @Samsquanch that link you posted is really what I have been looking for I think, thanks!

Comment: You could do this in several... Depending on how much information you have to track in each step. If you don't want to store information in each step then you have to override form submit default behaviour and preserve information in each step, then merge all the information and send it all in one big post. In this case all forms must be in one document and you are not technically posting anything,,, just preserving data from each form in each step. You can do this without forms too.. Second way would be to use AJAX, post each request data, store it, return a flag to move on to the next form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can change the HTML:

Add in a hidden field to the last form:

```
<input type="hidden" id="form_values" name="form_values" value="">
```

Then use the jQuery [`.submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) function to catch the form submit:

```
$('#form-ContactInfo').submit(function(event) {
  $('#form_values').val($('form').serialize());
});
```

Which you can then use to get the values using [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
parse_str($_POST['form_values'], $form_values);
// $form_values['channel_type'][0], etc
```

One thing to note, a lot of your fields are missing the `name` attribute. You'll need to add those in.

[Fiddle demoing the JS portion.](http://jsfiddle.net/nymo208w/)

Comment: Thanks for the help however this does not seem to work, even the JSFiddle demo does not work, it only shows the values of 1 of the forms

Comment: Now on my last Form, should I not have it POST to a URL?  When I do, it ends up just POSTING the contents of the last form and the hidden field `form_values` ends up being empty, any ideas how I can get this method you proposed to work all the way through the submit/post process?  Thanks for the help

Comment: Nevermind....it does work, on my last form, the JS you provided, I was targeting the wrong ID for the form, now it does submit all the fields to my PHP, thanks!