# Django - how to submit multiple forms

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I have a page with 5 different 'tabs' (implemented using "Materialize CSS"). Each tab has its own form (I have 5 different forms, I guess it's not a good idea to have one form for all the different tabsa).

What I want to do is, when I click "submit" button, all the forms/tabs that are filled out should be submitted (and all the empty ones should not do anything).

Any suggestions how should I implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: You may use js [FormData](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9280720/5644965) to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use self.data in the method to access the POST data before validation. It should contain a key called sub1 or sub2 depending on which button was pressed.

```
 <form method='POST'>
{{form1.as_p}}
<button type="submit" name="sub1">Save Changes</button>
</form>
<form method='POST'>
{{form2.as_p}}
<button type="submit" name="sub2">Save Changes</button>
</form>
```

code

```
if request.method=='POST' and 'sub1' in request.POST:
    do something...
if request.method=='POST' and 'sub2' in request.POST:
    do something...
```

Hope for helping you .