# How to pass multiple form datas with one submit button

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, forms

I am trying to post forms with multilanguages. For example i have en, es, ru language. I need to save en to the one table. Es and ru forms are must save into the translations table. But i can't pass the all datas to the controller@store function. How can i pass all datas with separatedly to the controller?

I am passing languages with compact. Like that:

```
public function index()
{
    $langs = [];
    foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $localeCode => $properties)
    {
        $langs[]= $localeCode;
    }

    return view('backEnd.langview', compact('langs'));
}
```

In the view i have tab panel for each language. This is the view:

```
@foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $localeCode => $properties)
@if($loop->first)
    <div class="tab-pane animated fadeIn text-muted active" id="tab{{$localeCode}}" aria-expanded="false">{{$localeCode}}
        <form method="POST" id="form{{$localeCode}}" action="{{route('send_slug')}}">
        {{csrf_field()}}
            <input type="text" name="main_title" placeholder="title here">
            <input type="text" name="main_slug" placeholder="slug here">
        </form>
    </div>
@else
    <div class="tab-pane animated fadeIn text-muted" id="tab{{$localeCode}}" aria-expanded="false">{{$localeCode}}
    <form method="POST" id="form{{$localeCode}}" action="{{route('send_slug')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}
        <input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="title here other languages">
        <input type="text" name="slug[]" placeholder="slug here other languages">

    </form>
    </div>
@endif
```

@endforeach

I was tried that with ajax:

```
<script>
var langcodes = @json($langs);
var i = 0;
submitForms = function(){
    langcodes.forEach(function (data) {
        i++;
        var formdata = $('#form'+data).serialize();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '{{route('send_slug')}}',
            method: 'post',
            data: {
                formdata
            }
        });
    });
}
```

But every try, i just can pass first language, or last language. I need to send all languages with separatedly. 
I hope i can express myself. Sorry about my language. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize multiple forms together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280720/serialize-multiple-forms-together)

Comment: If it is help full my answer then please accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this for pass multiple form data in ajax

```
var formdata = $("#form1, #form1").serialize();
```

Comment: yes, this is usefull. But i need to use foreach (for each language). My forms id is 
id="form{{$localeCode}}". How can i get this problem. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

for using for each language loop to try blow code example:

```
<?php
$language = array();
foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $localeCode => $properties){
    $language[] = "#form".$localeCode;
}

$formString = implode(",",$language);

echo $formString;

?>

<script>
var forms = "<?php echo $formString;?>";
var formdata = $(forms).serialize();

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

At seeing your code, you don't need multiple forms to get what you want. You have to pass an array as request to your controller.

Comment: But i am making form for each language i have. For example i have 10 language. I am changing with radio buttons and i have one submit button. What can i do in this situation? I can't found any solution. I need to send requests to the controller as an array, like your said. But i didn't.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this ?

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('send_slug')}}">
    {{csrf_field()}}

    @foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $localeCode => $properties)
      <div>
          {{$localeCode}}
          <input type="hidden" name="response[i][lang]">

          @if($loop->first)
                <input type="text" name="response[i][title]" placeholder="title here">
                <input type="text" name="response[i][slug]" placeholder="slug here">
          @else
                <input type="text" name="response[i][title]" placeholder="title other language here">
                <input type="text" name="response[i][slug]" placeholder="slug other language here">
          @endif
      </div>
    @endforeach
 <button type="submit">Send</button>
 </form>
```