# How do i combine two forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to add all fields from form1 into form 2 when form2 is submitted
without having to know each value in form1 ahead of time

Comment: why the down vote? i am new to js/jquery and this is a legit question. i also did google and search here and didn't find what i was looking for.

Comment: This should help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341001/merge-values-from-two-forms-on-submit

Comment: Being as specific as possible and posting code will get you the best answers possible.

Comment: @Ab Cd, can you post on your answer the relevant code for what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: thanks. apparently i suck at google :p

Comment: its just forms....since i want to do it dynamically i didn't think the actual form fields mattered

Comment: oh only -3 ??? you guys are off your game today

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = $('#form1').serialize() + '&' + $('#form2').serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'your_url',
  data: data
});
```

Comment: yes, '&' should be added between 2 serialize datas

Answer (score 1):

acrashik is right but it needs a correction on line 1 to concatenate the strings properly:

```
var form1Data = $('#form1').serialize(),
   data = (form1Data !== "" ? form1Data + "&" : "") + $('#form2').serialize();
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'your_url',
  data: data
});
```