# MVC 4 - Pass Multiple forms to Controller Action from View using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing web application using MVC 4.0,

In View, I have rendered 2 different Partial views. Each Partial View is placed inside different Form tags. (Different forms are needed for my requirement)

One Partial View contains a button control. On click of this button, 2 different Partial views values need to be send to Controller Action. So I have to serialize my 2 different form and send those values to Controller Action.

How can I send 2 different form values to Controller action using jQuery?

jQuery:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function (e) {
            var currentForm = $("#divId1").find('form');
            var mainForm = $("#divId2").find('form');
            $.post("{Area}/{Controller}/ProcessData",{ inputData : currentForm.serialize(), availableData: mainForm.serialize()}, function (data) {
                $('#divId2').empty();
                $('#divId2').append(data);
            });
        });
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult ProcessData(FormCollection inputData, FormCollection availableData)
```

I'm not able to get values in controller action.

Answer :
I acheived it using ajax POST and data concatenation.

jQuery:

```
var currentFormData = currentForm.serialize();
        var mainFormData = mainForm.serialize();

        $.ajax({ type: "POST", url: "{Area}/{Controller}/ProcessData", data: currentFormData + "&" + mainFormData, cache: false }).done(function (html) {
            $("#divId2").empty();
            $("#divId2").append(html);
        });
```

Action:

```
public ActionResult ProcessData(FormCollection inputData, CustomModel availableData)
```

Comment: Post your code what you have tried so far....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html wasn't designed for such things and, generally speaking, you're trying to break incapsulation. Nevertheless, assuming you're know what you are doing, the possible solution for this requirement may be manual population of javascript object (for POST) or concatination of query parameters (for GET) and submission of the result.

Here is an example how to do that: [Merge values from two forms on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341001/merge-values-from-two-forms-on-submit)

Comment: I managed to achieve it based on the link provided by you. Thank you so much.