# How to return the multiple form value from single page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I created the two Form with multiple form fields. Based on selection it shows the fields depends on the selection

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('select#select_btn').change(function(){
 
    var sel_value = $('option:selected').val();
 if(sel_value==0)
 {
  //Resetting Form 
  $("#form_submit").empty();
  $("#form1").css({'display':'none'});
 }
 else{
  //Resetting Form 
  $("#form_submit").empty();
  
  //Below Function Creates Input Fields Dynamically 
     create(sel_value);
  
  //appending submit button to form
  $("#form_submit").append(
  $("<input/>",{type:'submit', value:'Sumbit'})
  )
  } 
 }); 
 
function create(sel_value){
   for(var i=1;i<=sel_value;i++)   
    {
    $("div#form1").slideDown('slow');
    
     $("div#form1").append(
  $("#form_submit").append(
  $("<div/>",{id:'head'}).append(
  $("<h3/>").text("Refer Form"+i)),
    $("<h7/>").text("Name: "),
  $("<input/>",  {type:'text', placeholder:'Name', name:'name_'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
     $("<br/>"),
     $("<h7/>").text("Mobile No: "),
  $("<input/>", {type:'text', placeholder:'Mobile', name:'mobile'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
     $("<br/>"),
         $("<h7/>").text("Email: "),
  $("<input/>", {type:'email', placeholder:'Email', name:'email_'+i}),
  $("<br/>"),
     $("<br/>"),
     $("<h7/>").text("City: "),
    $("<select>").append('<option val="0">--Select--</option>','<option val="1">One</option>','<option val="2">Two</option>','<option val="3">Three</option>','<option val="4">Four</option>','<option val="5">Five</option>'),
 $("<br/>"),
   $("<br/>"),
   $("<h7/>").text("Course: "),
    $("<select>").append('<option val="0">--Select--</option>','<option val="1">One</option>','<option val="2">Two</option>','<option val="3">Three</option>','<option val="4">Four</option>','<option val="5">Five</option>'),
  $("<hr/>"),
  $("<br/>")
                  ))
     }
 
 }
  
 
 
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="container">
<form  action="#" method="post">
   <p>Name:
        <input type="text" name="Name" />
    </p>
    <p>Email:
        <input type="text" name="player_email" />
    </p>
      <p>Mobile:
        <input type="text" name="mobile" />
    </p>
 </form>
     <p> Refer:

<div id="selected_form_code">
 <select id="select_btn">
 <option value="0">--Select--</option>
 <option value="1">One</option>
 <option value="2">Two</option>
 <option value="3">Three</option>
 <option value="4">Four</option>
 <option value="5">Five</option>
 </select>
 </div>

 <div id="form1"> 
  <form id="form_submit" action="#" method="post">
   <!-- dynamic Registration Form Fields Creates here-->
  </form>
 </div> 
<!------ right side advertisement div ----------------->

 
</div>
```

How to return the both form data? when try to print the value it shows the form data value in array but it did not print 1st form value. How to return all form field value.

Comment: have you tried having look at jquery ajax to post data or the xmlHTTP Request object in javascript?

Comment: You can't. You cannot simply submit two forms on single HTTP request. What you need to do is at client side you can combine the data from two forms and submit them as single form data.

Comment: @Alok You should make this an answer - might help people coming to this question try to do the same thing OP is trying to do

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you need :

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var bigdata = [];
    $.each($("form"), function(k, v){
    bigdata.push($(this).serializeArray());

    })
    console.log(bigdata);
})
```

[Live DEMO JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8axn4zxn/)

Comment: It works on my JSFiddle, why it can't work for you ?

Comment: i print the both form data

Comment: My JSFiddle print both form in 1 array like this bigdata = [main_form][form2-form3-form4] this is not what you need?

Comment: when print the value use print_r it shows the value generated by jquery. But it not print above form data value selection

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You cannot simply submit two forms on single HTTP request.
 What you need to do is at client side you can combine the data from two forms and submit them as single form data.

Follow the link to merge data from two seprate form and send as one.

[Merge values from two forms on submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341001/merge-values-from-two-forms-on-submit#answer-2369264)