# How can I merge two or more similiar forms in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, coffeescript

So I have an arbitrary number of forms, each of which is basically structured like this:

```
{ 
  budget_items: 
  { 
    item_1_id: {values}, 
    item_2_id: {values}, 
    item_3_id: {values} 
  }, 
  notes: 
  { 
    note_1_id: val, 
    note_2_id: val
  }
}
```

On a submission, I'd like to merge together all the forms that have changed into a single unit, pulling out any extra authenticity tokens, and submit that to the server.

What I have right now is an jQuery selector that contains all the forms that have changed. How can I efficiently merge these forms together before submission?

I have JQuery, and this is being written in CoffeeScript, but syntax-agnostic help is more than welcome.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
getAllModals = ->
  scope.find('.modal').filter ->
    shouldSubmitModal($(this))

getFormsFromModals = ->
  getAllModals().map ->
    $(this).find('.modal-body form').first()

scope.on 'submit', '#allCustomerForm', (event) ->
  formsToSubmit = getFormsFromModals()
  str = ''
  formsToSubmit.each ->
    str += $(this).serialize()
  console.log str
  return false
```

This naively puts each form object right next to the other one, it doesn't properly merge the `budget_items` and `notes` subsections before serializing.

---

This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341001/merge-values-from-two-forms-on-submit). I have more than two forms, and cannot hardcode a call to `serialize`, since the forms in need of serializing are dynamic. I'm also attempting to merge the forms in a more elaborate way than a simple append.

---

Update: Here is my attempt using `serialize`, which simply appends the forms together rather than doing a deep merge.

```
scope.on 'submit', '#allCustomerForm', (event) ->
  formsToSubmit = getFormsFromModals()
  formIDs = ['#allCustomerForm']
  formsToSubmit.each ->
    formIDs.push('#' + $(this).attr('id') + ' :input')
  console.log $(formIDs.join(', ')).serialize()
  false
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge values from two forms on submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341001/merge-values-from-two-forms-on-submit)

Comment: Oh, I could have left a comment about that here. I edited to explain the difference. That question was really helpful as proof what I'm looking for _should_ be doable.